# Issue in Displaying facebook friends profile picture

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cordova

I'm integrating facebook in my phonegap app, where facebook friends profile picture, names and birthday dates are displayed, now able to display name and birthday dates but not profile picture. i'm getting blue rectangular box question mark image in place of profile picture instead of profile picture.
  Please help me.

```
 function me() {
            FB.api('/me/friends', {fields: 'id, name, picture,birthday' },  function(response) {
                   if (response.error) {
                   alert(JSON.stringify(response.error));
                   } else {
                   var data = document.getElementById('data');
                   fdata=response.data;
                   console.log("fdata: "+fdata);
                   response.data.forEach(function(item) {
                                         var d = document.createElement('div');
                                         d.innerHTML = "<img src="+item.picture+item.birthday+"/>"+item.name+"<br>"+item.birthday;
                                         data.appendChild(d);
       }
  }
```

Comment: `<img src="+item.picture+item.birthday+"/>` what has `item.birthday` to do in img src tag?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the inner Html line code as below:

```
d.innerHTML = "<img src=" + item.picture + "/>" + item.name + item.birthday;
```